# why do i get a "Procfile declares types -> (none)" even when i have the correct Procfile?

Tags: heroku, sunspot, foreman, cedar

i am trying to run the bundled solr that comes with sunspot_solr gem by adding this one line to Procfile:

```
solr: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
```

**Procfile is spelled with a small 'f' and exists at my Rails root.**

i have not yet been able to get any processes mentioned in my Procfile running on heroku.

i have checked the other questions asked on StackOverflow related to the same topic, so don't point me there:

[What is the reason for "Procfile declares types -> (none)" in Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346221/what-is-the-reason-for-procfile-declares-types-none-in-heroku)

[Procfile declares types -> (none) in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537501/procfile-declares-types-none-in-heroku)

Comment: In the interest of making this a complete question where other people don't have to go hunting for information, which 'other questions' did you check? Is your Profile [named `Procfile` with a lower-case 'f'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346221/what-is-the-reason-for-procfile-declares-types-none-in-heroku)? Have you successfully pushed to heroku before with a Procfile that runs other things properly? Is your Procfile [at the base of your project, at the same level as requirements.txt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537501/procfile-declares-types-none-in-heroku)?

Comment: Thank you! It is always easier to help when we have more information :)

Comment: What do you get when you type `foreman check`? It should say something like `valid procfile detected (solr)`

Comment: got that.

`$ foreman check
valid procfile detected (solr)`

Comment: I'm not sure sunspot_solr normally runs through a Procfile. Are you using something like [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websolr#choosing-a-solr-client)? They mention adding `require 'sunspot/rails/tasks'` to your Rakefile. ALso, do you have `gem 'sunspot_rails'` in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

Usually Heroku [expects at least one process named `web` in your Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile):

> All the language and frameworks on the Cedar stack declare a web process type, which starts the application server.

Does your program run if you change your Procfile to say this instead -

`web: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start`

?

I'm not sure that simply seeing `Procfile declares types -> (none)` after a push means there is an error - the [Heroku 'Getting Started with Rails' article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3) has that output at the start too; they just change their Procfile later on to run the `web` process instead.

Comment: i am sure that won't work, as you're asking heroku to start solr as a web process, so it won't start the default web process. so i tried:  
`web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT  
solr: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start`. this too fails.

Comment: Are your `web` and `solr` definitions on separate lines? Did you have a `web` process declared before? With your `web` process declared does heroku say something other than `Procfile declares types -> (none)` now?

Comment: web and solr are on separate lines. even with web process mentioned in Procfile, heroku doesn't detect it.